# Compare the values of a column with a reference value in each group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have  a data.frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), outcome=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0), 
                 type=c("trt1","trt2", "control","trt1","trt2", "control"))

  id outcome type
1  1     0.1 trt1
2  1     0.2 trt2
3  1     0.3 control
4  2     0.1 trt1
5  2     0.2 trt2
6  2     0.0 control
```

I want to compare in each group the outcome value of the trt1 and trt2 with outcome value of the control. If the outcome value of the control is bigger or equal I need a new column with the yes indication and if not the no indication.

the desired outcome would look like this.

```
  id outcome type   new.col
1  1     0.1 trt1     yes
2  1     0.2 trt2     yes
3  1     0.3 control  yes or NA (optional)
4  2     0.1 trt1     no
5  2     0.2 trt2     no
6  2     0.0 control  no or NA (optional)
```

I am struggling a lot with this and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new.col = case_when(type == 'control' ~ NA_character_,
                            outcome[type == 'control'] >= outcome ~ 'yes',
                            TRUE ~ 'no')) %>%
  ungroup

#    id outcome type    new.col
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
#1     1     0.1 trt1    yes    
#2     1     0.2 trt2    yes    
#3     1     0.3 control NA     
#4     2     0.1 trt1    no     
#5     2     0.2 trt2    no     
#6     2     0   control NA
```