# Comparing grouped data to a reference case in each group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have  a data.frame that looks like this

```
    PersonId VoteId CaucusShortName IsLeader VoteValueName
1      89156      1    Conservative        0           Nay
2     105340      1    Conservative        0           Yea
3      72029      1    Conservative        1           Nay
4      89535      1         Liberal        0           Yea
5     110339      1         Liberal        1           Yea
6      25446      1     Independent        0           Nay
7      89156      2    Conservative        0  Did not vote
8     105340      2    Conservative        0           Nay
9      72029      2    Conservative        1           Nay
10     89535      2         Liberal        0           Yea
11    110339      2         Liberal        1           Yea
12     25446      2     Independent        0           Yea
```

For each VoteId-Caucus grouping, I would like to compare the value of the Caucus leader's vote to all other caucus members for that vote.

If the specific vote-caucus group does not have a given leader at that time (like independents above), then I'd like to just put NA. Each caucus only has a maximum of 1 leader for a given vote, which may change from one vote to another.

I would thus like to create the column `LeaderAgree` to be as follows

```
    PersonId VoteId CaucusShortName IsLeader VoteValueName LeaderAgree            
1      89156      1    Conservative        0           Nay           1
2     105340      1    Conservative        0           Yea           0
3      72029      1    Conservative        1           Nay           1
4      89535      1         Liberal        0           Yea           1
5     110339      1         Liberal        1           Yea           1
6      25446      1     Independent        0           Nay          NA
7      89156      2    Conservative        0  Did not vote           0
8     105340      2    Conservative        0           Nay           1
9      72029      2    Conservative        1           Nay           1
10     89535      2         Liberal        0           Yea           1
11    110339      2         Liberal        1           Yea           1
12     25446      2     Independent        0           Yea          NA
```

I've tried adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287462/compare-the-values-of-a-column-with-a-reference-value-in-each-group-using-dplyr), but I think it fails to take into account the fact that in my case the number of "controls"(leaders) may change across votes, and that some groups will not have a leader at all.

If it's any easier, I would also accept a solution that simply creates a column indicating the leader's vote for that vote-caucus group, which I could deal with myself, i.e.

```
    PersonId VoteId CaucusShortName IsLeader VoteValueName LeaderVote            
1      89156      1    Conservative        0           Nay        Nay
2     105340      1    Conservative        0           Yea        Nay
3      72029      1    Conservative        1           Nay        Nay
4      89535      1         Liberal        0           Yea        Yea
5     110339      1         Liberal        1           Yea        Yea
6      25446      1     Independent        0           Nay         NA
7      89156      2    Conservative        0  Did not vote        Nay
8     105340      2    Conservative        0           Nay        Nay
9      72029      2    Conservative        1           Nay        Nay
10     89535      2         Liberal        0           Yea        Yea
11    110339      2         Liberal        1           Yea        Yea
12     25446      2     Independent        0           Yea         NA
```

Comment: In row 3 why is `LeaderAgree` equal to 1 if the other two group votes are divided, one `Nay` and the other `Yea`?

Comment: I'm not concerned with what other people are voting, but simply whether each member agrees with their leader. 

So in row 3, that person is the leader of the Conservative caucus for vote #1. By definition, they always agree with the leader (themself) so they get LeaderAgree=1. I'd like to also compare rows 1 and 2 with what the leader (row 3) voted, and if it matches those rows also get LeaderAgree=1, otherwise they get 0 (or NA if that caucus has no leader to compare to).


Similarly I'd like to compare row 4 with the Liberal caucus leader's vote in row 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way. The condition in `ifelse` is `TRUE` whenever there is a leader in the group. If there isn't a leader in the group assign `NA` to the new column, if there is compare the votes with the leader's vote. Then coerce to integer.

I have left the posted expected result as is, and created a new column, `LeaderAgree2`, to make the comparisons with the expected result easier.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df1 %>%
  group_by(VoteId, CaucusShortName) %>%
  mutate(
    LeaderAgree2 = ifelse(as.logical(IsLeader) | any(IsLeader),
                          VoteValueName == VoteValueName[as.logical(IsLeader)],
                          NA),
    LeaderAgree2 = as.integer(LeaderAgree2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 12 × 7
#> # Groups:   VoteId, CaucusShortName [6]
#>    PersonId VoteId CaucusShortName IsLeader VoteValueName LeaderAgree LeaderAg…¹
#>       <int>  <int> <chr>              <int> <chr>               <int>      <int>
#>  1    89156      1 Conservative           0 Nay                     1          1
#>  2   105340      1 Conservative           0 Yea                     0          0
#>  3    72029      1 Conservative           1 Nay                     1          1
#>  4    89535      1 Liberal                0 Yea                     1          1
#>  5   110339      1 Liberal                1 Yea                     1          1
#>  6    25446      1 Independent            0 Nay                    NA         NA
#>  7    89156      2 Conservative           0 Did not vote            0          0
#>  8   105340      2 Conservative           0 Nay                     1          1
#>  9    72029      2 Conservative           1 Nay                     1          1
#> 10    89535      2 Liberal                0 Yea                     1          1
#> 11   110339      2 Liberal                1 Yea                     1          1
#> 12    25446      2 Independent            0 Yea                    NA         NA
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​LeaderAgree2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
PersonId VoteId CaucusShortName IsLeader VoteValueName LeaderAgree            
1      89156      1    Conservative        0           Nay           1
2     105340      1    Conservative        0           Yea           0
3      72029      1    Conservative        1           Nay           1
4      89535      1         Liberal        0           Yea           1
5     110339      1         Liberal        1           Yea           1
6      25446      1     Independent        0           Nay          NA
7      89156      2    Conservative        0  'Did not vote'           0
8     105340      2    Conservative        0           Nay           1
9      72029      2    Conservative        1           Nay           1
10     89535      2         Liberal        0           Yea           1
11    110339      2         Liberal        1           Yea           1
12     25446      2     Independent        0           Yea          NA
", header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hmm. When I run your code as you've shown it, reading in df1 as you did, I do not get the LeaderAgree2 that you do. I get `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE` for that new column, which doesn't correspond to the `1 0 1 1 1...` that you've shown if it were converted to numeric.

Comment: @Rubberduckquack I cannot reproduce that behavior, I have just tested it again and the code I have posted outputs what I have posted.

Comment: Works correctly for me too. @Rubberduckquack, are you running @RuiBarradas’ code exactly as provided, including the `LeaderAgree2 = as.integer(LeaderAgree2)` line? It would be very strange if your column were still logical after running `as.integer()`.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I'm not sure what was wrong (perhaps something to do with plyr being loaded along with dplyr) but I ran it again and it works. Thanks for all the help, it seems to work on my full data as well.